# Django - Left joning two queryset from different database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models from different database and server:

```
# This is from server A, database A1
class employee_info(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(db_column='First_name', max_length=255)

# This is from server B, database B1
class vehicles(models.Model):
    vehicle_id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(db_column='vehicle_type', max_length=255)
    emp_id= models.IntegerField(db_column='emp_id')  # No Foreign Key Constaints
```

This is my querying

```
def getinfo():
    vehicles = vehicles.objects.using('ServerA').all()
    emp_info = employee_info.objects.using('ServerB').all()

    # How do I do a left join on vehicles with emp_info base on 'emp_id' column of both queryset?
    vehicle_with_emp_info = ??? # vehicles LEFT JOIN emp_info ON vehicles.emp_id = emp_info.emp_id, but how?
    return vehicle_with_emp_info
```

How should I go about joining the two query set? Is there a way to do this?

If there is no solution, is there an alternative? I only care about displaying the resulting data on the client's side in a table format.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, django does not support cross-database-relations (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations). You can transform your querysets to plain python objects and "knit" it together.

Comment: Any recommendation on how to transform the query set into plain python objects? I have tried transforming it into a dataframe, but the dataframe library seem to cause my django application to freeze all together without error warning(I am using a stack with Apache, and Django)